# How to know evicted entries in Redis cache

Tags: redis, jedis

I wanted to use a Redis cache to store some entires. But when cache eviction occurs, I need to know the entry which got evicted. What APIs we have to know the entry which got evicted. This is because based on the value, I wanted to do some memory cleanup in my application

Comment: @for_stack do evicted entries considered as expired ?

Comment: @Ersoy My BAD! You should subscribe the evicted event, NOT the expired event: *Evicted events (events generated when a key is evicted for maxmemory*. Check the [doc](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) for detail.

Comment: Thank you @for_stack for explanation and link